# Не работает валидация asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net

Всем здрасте. Проблема абсолютно идентична [этой](http://www.cyberforum.ru/asp-net-mvc/thread640261.html)

В чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эта строка:  ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Clear(); случайно завалялась в Global.asax.
Из-за этого все пляски.